# Delete query using COUNT and MIN. MS Access 2010

Tags: duplicates, ms-access-2010, delete-row

I am trying to identify and remove duplicates from a data extract.

I have setup a query to group by `contract_number` and `count > 1` which identifies the cases and there are two `contract_start_date`'s of which I need to remove the earliest so I have applied min.

I am unable to run this as delete query. I am fairly new to Access and SQL Scripts.

```
SELECT Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER, 
       Count(Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER) AS CountOfCONTRACT_NUMBER, 
       Min(Gas_Data.CONTRACT_START_DATE) AS MinOfCONTRACT_START_DATE

FROM Gas_Data

GROUP BY Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER

HAVING (((Count(Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER))>1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach where you, in the subquery, identify those records *not* to be deleted:

```
DELETE 
    *
FROM 
    Gas_Data
WHERE 
    Gas_Data.CONTRACT_START_DATE Not IN
    (SELECT 
        Max(T.CONTRACT_START_DATE)
    FROM 
        Gas_Data As T
    WHERE 
        T.CONTRACT_NUMBER = Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER)
```

Of course, do make a backup first.

Comment: Having also posted an answer, I actually prefer the logic of your suggestion - have my upvote sir.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMac. I learned that method many years ago and also liked the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
delete from gas_data a 
where exists 
(
    select top 1 * from gas_data b 
    where 
    a.contract_number = b.contract_number and 
    a.contract_start_date < b.contract_start_date
)
```

For every record, the above will test whether there is at least one other record in the dataset for which the contract number is equal and the start date is later. If such a record exists, the earlier record is deleted.

Always retain a backup of your data before running `delete` queries.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM Gas_Data
WHERE Count(Gas_Data.CONTRACT_NUMBER)>1
```

Comment: and what about only deleting the duplicate with the earliest date (Contract start date MIN)

Comment: Uh, that query will delete all items from those contract numbers.